# workaround to using ID in <a> to call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an XML file that has a number for each section. The page loads a link for each section of the XML and puts the article number in the URL parameter (page.html?aid=###). When the link is clicked an overlay iframe pops up the with more information about that article.  is calling the overlay iframe popup but I can't use more than one of the same ID for a page.

```
$(function(){
    $('#b1').frameWarp();
});
```

Instead of using ID="b1", am I able to use each article number for the id? I cannot use class instead of ID.
Would there be another way to do this?

Comment: Does your `.frameWarp()` function use the element's ID to determine which page to show in the iframe?

Comment: Show us your actual HTML and we can give you a much better idea what your options are

Comment: Am I missing something? I thought $("#blah").attr("id") would return blah.

Comment: $('#b1').frameWarp();
I need the 1 to be anything so that I can use any id="b#####" and still call the function

Comment: I still don't get the gist. If you want multiple a-tags to open the same popup then why don't you just put the information that tells which page to open into any other attribute than the id (XML - data-* for HTML5) and retreive it from there?

Comment: http://valhallamod.com/test/ here is an example. the class row doesn't work which is why I'm not going to use it (the page won't refresh after the first link is clicked). I disabled the overlay so its just an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer courtesy of benalpert on reddit:
$('.b1').each(function() { $(this).frameWarp(); })
This allows the class to be used instead of ID without error.
Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$('a[id^="b"]')`, but that's hugely inefficient and will probably match more than what you want it to. Alternatively, you could filter on a regex:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    var re = /^b[0-9]+$/;
    return re.test($(this).attr('id'));
}).frameWarp();
```

It's not much more efficient, if at all, but at least it would rule out false positives.